# How does Boost use stream insertion directly into C strings?

Tags: c++, boost

In [this example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/test_output/contexts.html), and several related pages, Boost appears to use the stream insertion operator (<<) directly on a const char array.

```
BOOST_TEST_INFO("With parameter j = " << j);
```

With or without 'BOOST_TEST_INFO' or other macros, I consistently get the expected compiler error

```
error: invalid operands of type const char[#] and int to binary operator<<
```

There is a file called basic_cstring.hpp deep in the Boost headers that I assume is relevant, but it isn't explicitly included in the example (and including from my source doesn't seem to make a difference.) What am I missing?

**Edit** - stream insertion operators are chosen if and only if the surrounding macro is discovered during preprocessing; otherwise, the first error is the red herring "invalid operators ... to binary operator". Supplying the exact same line into BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE succeeds, but BOOST_TEST_INFO, BOOST_TEST_CONTEXT, etc. weren't declared, which is a separate issue (as far as I can tell).

Comment: Hint: `<<` is not `,`, and the whole string (`"With parameter j = " << j`) becomes an argument to a macro.

Comment: re your edit: obviously the macro is only expanded by the preprocessor if the macro has actually been defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy to see preprocessed output - that helps understanding it. For example, use following code snipped:

```
#define CHECK(x) std::cout << x

CHECK("Oh" << "My" << "Gott" << 42 << "!");
```

And run a compiler in 'output preprocessed code' mode (often `-E` switch). You will see following:

`~>g++ -E cc.cpp`

```
# 1 "cc.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "cc.cpp"


std::cout << "Oh" << "My" << "Gott" << 42 << "!";
```

And that is clear, isn't it?

Comment: Can you think of a reason why BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE would be declared, but BOOST_TEST_INFO, BOOST_TEST_CONTEXT, etc. wouldn't, despite using the one and only include listed on the example page? It looks like that's the real reason I got that error.

Comment: `BOOST_TEST_INFO` is new in Boost 1.60 (which is the version those docs cover). Are you sure you're using that version? If not, you should probably be reading the docs for the version you're using. Boost.Test underwent big API changes recently.

Comment: That was the issue - I assumed the repository I was using would be up to date, which was why I looked up the most recent docs in the first place. To the source I go.

Answer (score 6):

The macro expands to `SOMETHING << "With parameter j = " << j` so it's not inserting anything into the string literal, any more than `cout << 1 << 2` inserts `2` into `1`.